# How change temporary primary group for user when user connect to samba?

Tags: samba, pam

I have samba connected via Winbind to AD. Historically, all unix enabled users has wrong primary group.

May I change while user connected to samba primary group to one of the users secondary? It could be like `preexec = bash -c 'newgrp "GROUPNAME"'` (that doesn't work)

Mb smh like PAM modification?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're looking for `username map` option, which can help you to remap users's wrong primary group to a proper one.